# Programatically copy XLSX styles from one file to another

Tags: excel, xlsx

We are generating large XLSX documents (only data) and we have template XLSX  (styles, image, etc...).

I know XLSX is just zip, you can extract them look what is inside.

It's possible somehow to copy styles & formatting from template XLSX file to generated XLSX document (copy xl/styles.xml file and zip that again is not enough). Excel complains the file is not ok, so I think there are some consistency checks?...

Thanks

Comment: Please post the specific Excel error message so the community is able to assist

Comment: This is not about error messages, because I am looking for a procedure on how to do that... I try simply copy `xl/styles.xml` and zip again but it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

We built a Python-based tool to copy XLSX styles from one sheet to another, allowing you to essentially template the visual design of a spreadsheet and apply it to new data.

https://github.com/Sydney-Informatics-Hub/copy_xlsx_styles may solve your needs.